# Trouble with string mining from rvest results

Tags: r, regex, rvest

I'm mining species data from this page which offers no API or downloadable list:

```
    library(rvest)
      moltres<-1:30
     for (i in moltres){
      temphtml<-read_html(paste0("http://checklist.aou.org/taxa/",i)) %>%
      html_node("section") %>%
      html_text()
      pidgey<-rbind(pidgey, temphtml)
      }
```

Outcome comes like this, for each item on the list:

```
"\n  \n      species: \n      Chen canagica (Emperor Goose, Oie empereur)\n  \n\n\n\nNOTE: This is an invalidated taxon. It is a 'synonym' for 12681, which has superseded it.\n\n\n\n\t\n  Compare AOU treatments of \n    \n        Chen canagica,\n in Avibase\n     (1886 to present).\n  \n\n\tSearch for \n    \n        Chen canagica\n at Cornell Birds of North America.\n  \n\n\n\n\n    Annotation: Monotypic.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t"
```

I'm trying to extract the code 12681 in every "It is a 'synonym' for 12681"
(these are the up-to-date names of the species)

I tried with:

```
pidgey$sub<-sub(".*synonim (.*?)\\,.*", "\\1", pidgey)
```

but it makes a big mess with the original list I 'rvested, and at the end there's a column which doesn't contain what I want, I think it has to do with the text format,
I appreciate your help enormously

Comment: you've spelt synonym wrong in your regex, you haven't accounted for the `'` after synonym. Try `synonym' .*?([0-9]*),` or something close to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the text changes due to locale, but this will match "synonym" or "synonim" and get the # you desire:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringi)

moltres <- 1:30

pb <- progress_estimated(length(moltres))
map_df(moltres, ~{

  pb$tick()$print()

  Sys.sleep(sample(1:5, 1)) # be kind, you have time and the resource is free

  pg <- read_html(sprintf("http://checklist.aou.org/taxa/%s", .x))

  data_frame(
    res = .x, 
    txt = html_node(pg, "section") %>% html_text() 
  )

}) -> xdf

xdf$synon <- stri_match_first_regex(xdf$txt, "'synon[yi]m' for ([[:digit:]]+)")[,2]

select(xdf, synon) %>% 
  print(n=30)
## # A tibble: 30 x 1
##    synon
##    <chr>
##  1  <NA>
##  2  <NA>
##  3  <NA>
##  4  <NA>
##  5  <NA>
##  6  <NA>
##  7  <NA>
##  8  <NA>
##  9  <NA>
## 10  <NA>
## 11  <NA>
## 12  <NA>
## 13  <NA>
## 14  <NA>
## 15  <NA>
## 16 12681
## 17 12691
## 18 12701
## 19  <NA>
## 20  <NA>
## 21  <NA>
## 22  <NA>
## 23  <NA>
## 24  <NA>
## 25  <NA>
## 26  <NA>
## 27  <NA>
## 28  <NA>
## 29  <NA>
## 30  <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked in spite of my mispellings! Awesome!